# Hilbert series of filtered algebras

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R=\mathbb{Q}[x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n]$ and $I$ a non-homogeneous ideal of $R$.  Then the algebra R/I is filtered. It has an associated graded algebra gr(R/I).

Let $I_1$ be the initial ideal of $I$, see for example [the paper](https://mast.queensu.ca/~ggsmith/Papers/monomials_m2.pdf). Then $I_1$ is a homogeneous ideal of $R$ and $R/I_1$ is a graded algebra.

Is the Hilbert series of gr(R/I) the same as the Hilbert series of $R/I_1$? Thank you very much.

Comment: The answer is affirmative: a general fact that isn't hard to prove is that $\mathrm{gr}(R/I)$ and $R/\mathrm{in}(I)$ are isomorphic as (graded) algebras. But (as per question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/325312/standard-reference-name-for-initial-ideals-leftrightarrow-associated-graded) I'm lacking a good reference =)